# How to stop resizing chart.js in case hovered and out of boundaries?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an example on chartJs.When you hovered the chart,two lines appears.

```
var data_set = [{x: 1, y: 12}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 8}, {x: 6, y: 8}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 2}, {x: 9, y: 3}, {x: 10, y: 5}, {x: 11, y: 11}, {x: 12, y: 1}];
   //draw lines on yAxis.
    addLine(3.5);
    addLine(7);
```

In this example `y` coordinates of data_set are not underneath the addedLines.But when I change the `y:12` to `y:1` on first index of data_set and draw line like `addLine(11.5)`,chart rescales to make it always within boundaries.I wanna break this behavior.I never ever want it to be rescaled onhover state.How to do that?

Example on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckhf0q9g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up axes ticks. It works as expected with these scales:

```
    scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      id: 'x-axis',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return data.labels[index];
        }
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis',
      type: 'linear',
      ticks: {
        max: 12,
        min: 1,
        stepSize: 1,
      }
    }],
  }
```